# C loop while - beginner

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

My first question here on forum. I'm not sure why the output of the code is "hi" whereas I'm thinking it should be null. I might be missing here something badly. Help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)    
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0)
    {
        printf("hi\n");
        i++;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the output should not be `hi`?

Comment: Please explain what kind of output you would expect from your program.

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop will run what you have enclosed in it up until the stopping condition is false. you have `int i = 0` as your starting value and your while loop condition says `while (i == 0)` to print "hi". Since i = 0, your condition is true one time and will print "hi" once before i increments and becomes false on the next pass.

Answer (score 1):

The output of your code is correct, the `while` loop is entered because `i == 0` and then `i` changes to `1` so the condition is false on the second iteration which makes the loop end and thus the program too.

Comment: Thanks guys. brain fart. I don't know what I got into.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing while loops with until loops (which C doesn't have). The while loop will execute its body **while** a condition is true, not **until** it is true. So if you want to print "hi" 10 times, you will need to write

```
int i = 1;

while (i <= 10) {
    printf("hi\n");
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)    
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0)
    {
        printf("hi\n");
        i++;    
    }
}
```

while loop works in such a way that the loop executes only if the condition inside the parenthesis is true. In the above code, the value of 'i' is initially set to 0, which satisfies the condition of the while loop. It enters inside the loop, goes on to print 'hi' and then increments the value of 'i'.

Now the condition of while is again checked. Since the condition fails this time ,as the value of 'i' has been incremented, it exits out of the loop and the program terminates. I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

like @iharob said, i==0 returns 1 which creates an infinite loop running and printing hi hi hi hi hi

if i was to do them, I would put in an if statement inside the while loop to check if i is still 0 or changed. if its 0, print hi, else, return 0;

Comment: And we need a separate `if` expression apart from the one which `while` has because..?

Answer (score -1):

it is obvious that the syntax that your are looking for is a `do ... while` loop

because programs run from up to down and left to right, the moment that your program reaches the `while` checks the `i` and it is still `0`  but for the next loop it won't print anything because `i=1`.